# call array items with a delay using in swift - get UIResponder error

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nstimer, uiresponder

Searching around didn't seem to provide anything that I understood straight away.

I'm trying to make a stupid 'old skool' loading screen for an app which will print out 'DOS like' statements.

My current code looks like this, but I get a UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate error - EXE_BAD_ACCESS

I've tried copying this to a new project etc. still get the same error.

Code below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var loadingLBL: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var logoIMG: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        //fades logo image in 
        logoIMG.alpha = 0
        UIView.animateWithDuration(5, animations: {
            self.logoIMG.alpha = 1;
        })

        //array for loading text

        var loading = ["Loading please wait.......\n", "Registry , OK!\n", `"Available ram, 256k\n", "BIOS Load... OK\n", "Welcome" ]`

        var i = 0
        var str: String = ""
        var timer = NSTimer()

        //delay function for loading array text

        func delayFunc() {
            str += "\(loading[i])\n"
            loadingLBL.text = str
            if i == loading.count - 1 {
                timer.invalidate()
            }
            i += 1
        }

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector(delayFunc()), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }   
}
```

As I mentioned, I get a crash and I've no idea what I've done wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: To learn how to debug a crash, please visit http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: After you learn how to debug, update your question with specific details about the crash including the full error message and the line that actually causes the error.

Comment: After doing what @rmaddy recommended. I would start by removing your **timer**, **i**, & **str** variables from your viewDidLoad along with your delayFunc. All of those should be at the class level... also, your timers selector parameter should be #selector(ViewController.delayFunc)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that delayFunc() is in viewDidLoad, the selector is looking in the viewController but can't find the function (because it is in viewDidLoad)

Edit: I wasn't 100% clear about why the selector can't find delayFunc when it's in viewDidLoad. If you declare a function within another function's body it's lifetime is at most the lifetime of its 'parent' function. So when your timer tries to call delayFunc, delayFunc doesn't exist anymore because viewDidLoad has finished running.

Try:

```
var i = 0
var str: String = ""
var timer = NSTimer()

var loading = ["Loading please wait.......\n", "Registry , OK!\n", "Available ram, 256k\n", "BIOS Load... OK\n", "Welcome" ]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //fades logo image in 
    logoIMG.alpha = 0
    UIView.animateWithDuration(5, animations: {
        self.logoIMG.alpha = 1;
    })

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "delayFunc", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func delayFunc() {
    str += "\(loading[i])\n"
    loadingLBL.text = str
    if i == loading.count - 1 {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
    i += 1
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```